# Window Switch is not working in selenium

Tags: selenium, switch-statement, window

I'm working with Selenium Automation. In this, When I click a link in a current window, a new window opens. I just want to switch the control to the new window. But I can't do this. Actually the new window is an auto-generated one. That is, link will be generated dynamically. Help me friends.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class UAN {
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
            File file = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver ();
            driver.get("http://intraeasy.techmahindra.com/easyhome.aspx");
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();   
            System.out.println("Main window value: "+Parent_Window);
            //CLick to open new window
           driver.findElement(By.linkText("People Search")).click();
           // Switching from parent window to child window   
           for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles())  
             driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);
          {
          // Performing actions on child window  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("test");
       // Switching back to Parent Window
         driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window); 
      }
    }
}
```

Code is giving below error while executing this line.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("test");


Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == notetext (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 5.11 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written your code like:-

```
for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles())  
     driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);
  {
  // Performing actions on child window  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("test");
  // Switching back to Parent Window
 driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window); 
}
```

The logic is wrong itself. You need to find all the windows separately and then switch over it.

```
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterate = windows.iterator();
String parentWindow = iterate.next();
String childWindow = iterate.next();
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
// do your action
```